# Get Android module's Package Name from Main Project

Tags: android, package-name, android-module

How can get the Android module's `Package Name` from `Main Project`?
The main project contains some Module.
    getPackageName()
return the App Package Name

Comment: What mean by project module? in java class, you can just use `getPackageName()`

Comment: did you ever try to look it in google before asking the question ?

Comment: The main project contains some Module. getPackageName() return the Module's Package Name

Answer (score -2):

you can get package name like this :

```
String pname=getPackageName();
```

Comment: This should be comment and not an answer

Comment: getPackageName() return the Module's Package Name